# Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC)

Tags: c#, .net, tivoli

I have a c# console app that reads excel. The app works fine when executed locally on the server, however we want to schedule it through IBM Tivoli Workload Scheduler (Maestro).

When executed from the scheduler I get Unhandled Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The .Net Framework Data Providers
>   require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install
>   Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829} failed due
>   to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Server is Windows 2008 R2. The scheduler account is an administrator on the box. What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try : Reinstall Visual Studio, reinstall Microsoft Office, download and install Microsoft Data Access Components : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793

I have the same problem and even though I did all of them, none worked for me. Maybe they'll work for you. Best of luck!